# Compare list with multiple values

Tags: python, list

Ok , I have figured what I should do.
I have a list with words:

```
T_buffer=docs_A_rec[key]['words']
```

which contains:

```
['from', 
'wiml', 
'stein', 
'focus', ...]
```

and i have another list (templist) which contains:

```
[('focus', -7.734475849276923e-07), 
('four', -7.734475849276923e-07), 
('rapid', -7.734475849276923e-07),
...]
```

I want for each word in T_buffer to compare it with the all the words in templist (1st element in all tuples of list)
If a word is matched then i want to store inside the dict the word and the value of the templist:
`docs_A_rec[key]['idf']=templist (word,number)`
if word does ot exists in the templist then i want to store inside the dict the word that it does not exists in templist and 0
`docs_A_rec[key]['idf']=(word,0)`

Something like this one:

```
for key in docs_A_rec:
   T_buffer=docs_A_rec[key]['words']
   if [item for item in T_buffer if item in templist]:
       `docs_A_rec[key]['idf']=templist`
   else:
       `docs_A_rec[key]['idf']=[item,0]
```

Thannks in advance !

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: this contains a list full of words not numbers:
docs_A_rec[infile]['word']
i want for each word inside the list to compare it with the templist's words and if they match then dict[word]['idf']=templist(word,number) otherwise dict[word]['idf']=templist(word,0)

Comment: Can you simply post sample (perhaps simplified) input and expected output? At the moment it is difficult to say what input do you have. Just tell us what you have, what you need and why do you think your approach fails.

Comment: i think i should create a loop inside the last loop which will accessing the elements of 'words' list one by one and compare them with the elements of the templist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are talking about, a greatly simplified example:

```
templist = [('word',1234.555),('word2',5534342.3434)]
compare_dict['word'] = ['word','another word','home']
```

Given the above:

> I want for each word inside the list to compare it with the templist's
>   words and if they match then `dict[word]['idf']=templist(word,number)`
>   otherwise `dict[word]['idf']=templist(word,0)`

```
for word, number in templist:
    if word in compare_dict['word']:
        compare_dict['idf'][word] = number
    else:
        compare_dict['idf'][word] = 0
```